# Parse url with arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex, parsing

I have input url from GET method in the following format

```
rec_test.html?emotion=Happy&myInputs_1%5B%5D=things&myInputs_1%5B%5D=are&myInputs_1%5B%5D=working&myInputs_2%5B%5D=i&myInputs_2%5B%5D=hope&myInputs_3%5B%5D=so
```

I am trying to parse it with the following code:

```
function getParameterByName(name){
                    var url = window.location.search;
                    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
                    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)");
                    results = regex.exec(url);
                    if (!results) return null;
                    if (!results[2]) return '';
                    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
                }
```

but when I pass `myInputs_1` to the function, it returns null.

I somehow plan on generating the output in the format:

```
myInput_1 = ['things', 'are', 'working']
myInput_2 = ['i', 'hope']
myInput_3 = ['so']
```

but I am not able to extract the individual values. Is there a way to achieve the desired output?

edit_1

I learned that `%5B` is `[` and `%5D` is `]`, but even if I pass `myInput_1[]` as parameter to the function, it still returns null, I have no idea why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a while loop when using `.exec` to [find successive matches](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec#Finding_successive_matches). Also, I simplified your regex.

```
function getParameterByName(name){
    var url = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search);
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)", 'g');
    var match, result = [];
    while ((match = regex.exec(url)) !== null)
        result.push(match[1]);
    return result;
}
```

I suggest you go with Jean's answer unless you browser compatibility matters to you.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) object of a [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) instance:

```
s = "http://example.com/rec_test.html?emotion=Happy&myInputs_1%5B%5D=things&myInputs_1%5B%5D=are&myInputs_1%5B%5D=working&myInputs_2%5B%5D=i&myInputs_2%5B%5D=hope&myInputs_3%5B%5D=so"

url = new URL(s)
searchParams = url.searchParams

console.log(searchParams.getAll("myInputs_1[]"))
// ["things", "are", "working"]
```

Comment: your answer is really concise, but I have a browser compatibility requirement. In future, if possible, people should use this.

Answer (score 0):

Non regex way

```
function getParamByName(name){
    var value = []
    paramsArray = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search).split("?")[1].split("&")
    paramsArray.forEach(function(d){
        if(d.indexOf(name) > -1){
            value.push(d.split("=")[1])
        }
    })
    return value;
}
```